# How to bind to a custom event handler in XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having some difficulty figuring out how to properly bind a custom event handler from my XAML instead of my code behind. In my code behind I current have this in my parent code behind:

`this.stepBar.Callback = SetViewForStep;`

This works fine and it will properly set the Callback event handler in my custom control which is defined as follows:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CallbackProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Callback), typeof(EventHandler), typeof(StepProgressBarControl), null);

public EventHandler Callback {
            get {
                return (EventHandler)GetValue(CallbackProperty);
            } set {
                SetValue(CallbackProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

However, I would like to be able to define it purely in XAML the same way one might define a `Click` event on a button.

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Padding="20" Spacing="20">
            <customcontrols:StepProgressBarControl 
                StepColor="LightPink" 
                Steps="5" 
                Callback="SetViewForStep"
                StepSelected="{Binding SelectedStep}" x:Name="stepBar" />
            <Label
               Text="{Binding SelectedStep, StringFormat='The Step Selected is {0}'}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontSize="Large"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
```

However, if I define it in the XAML and try to run it I get a compile error of  `Error   XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Callback", or mismatching type between value and property.`

How can I create an EventHandler such that I can define its function in my xaml.cs the same way one might define a click event for a button or any other built in control that has an exposed EventHandler property?

Comment: I use caliburn.micro for MVVM. You can easily execute functions in your viewmodel when events are fired. It also makes binding to most controls as easy as naming it the same as a property or method in your ViewModel. i.e. a button named run when pressed will attempt to execute a method called run in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring `Callback` as `event` should be able to solve the problem .

Change your code in custom control as below

```
 public event EventHandler Callback;
```

In this way when we type `Callback` in xaml ,  the intellisense helps us to reference the method in page .

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, and now how would I actually go about invoking it in a similar vein to say when a button is clicked?

Comment: You should get to know what is event:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event , it is raised in the custom control not in page .